# Find wavelength using distance and angle in python

Tags: python

this is my professors example output

```
python
    This program calculates the wavelength given distance and angle
    Please enter the distance (nm): 0.025
    Please enter the angle (degrees): 25
    Wavelength is 0.0211 nm
```

this is my code

python

```
print("This program calculates the wavelength given distance and angle")
print("Please enter the distance (nm):")
nm = float(input())
print("Please enter the angle (degrees):")
d = float(input())
print("Wavelength is", nm * math.sin(d), "nm")
```

my code does not get anywhere close to his output, I have no clue which formula to use in order to get the same answer as him using only distance and angle.

Comment: Hint: Trigonometric functions expect angles in radians.

Comment: The program is obviously buggy w.r.t. its own print-outs — see comments about radians. However, it is also not clear what it is trying to compute, which seems to be a question better suited for the physics or math stack exchange sites,

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance you also have your wavelength equation wrong as well. Plugging in your numbers (even with radians) did not get the correct answer.

Review wavelength information here:

[https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~cass/courses/m309-03a/a1/clayton/part2.html](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecass/courses/m309-03a/a1/clayton/part2.html)